Making CoreData singleton concurrency-safe
Consider this CoreData stack written for Swift 5.10
import CoreData

final class CoreDataStack {
    
    static let shared = CoreDataStack()
    
    private init() { }
    
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyCoreData")
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()
    
    lazy var mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        context.automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent = true
        return context
    }()
       
    lazy var backgroundContext: NSManagedObjectContext = {
        let context = persistentContainer.newBackgroundContext()
        return context
    }()

    func saveContext () {
        guard mainContext.hasChanges else { return }
        do {
            try mainContext.save()
            print("AppDelegate persistentContainer saved data")
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            print("AppDelegate error savingContext \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}

When checking against Swift 6 it gives the warning

Static property 'shared' is not concurrency-safe because it is either not conforming to 'Sendable' or isolated to a global actor; this is an error in Swift 6


How do you build a CoreData stack so that it is concurrency-safe?

Do I need to make it a Sendable Struct, or an unchecked Sendable class (with appropriate locks & queues?
Or do I isolate it to a global actor (e.g. MainActor, and if so, how do I use the backgroundContext off the MainActor?

Make it an actor instead of a class. Also, singletons are an anti-pattern

Isolating it to the main actor is okay. You are supposed to use perform to run operations on the background context.

@Sweeper If I isolate the class to MainActor, I can't then use the var backgroundContext in any other actor, because it can't cross actor boundaries. Is this correct?
